# Expression Blend Error with design time data (no error in visual studio)

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, expression-blend-4

I created some design time data from my windows phone 7 application and when I look at designer in Visual Studio (Express), the design time data shows up perfectly fine. However when I try to load the same project in Expression blend 4 I get an error and the design time data doesn't show up.

The error that I get is very generic "Error found in 'my xaml class' " The exact line that it points to is:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=../DesignData/VendorDetailViewDesignData.xaml}"
...
>
```

I really have no idea what the problem could be since this works fine with the visual studio designer. Do I have to do something different for expression blend?

To create the design time data I basically followed

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/08/27/designdata-mvvm-support-in-blend-vs2010-and-wpf-silverlight.aspx
and took the default windows phone projects that have design time data in them as an example.

The xaml class is in a the folder rootFolder/View/ while the design time data files are in rootFolder/DesignData/

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!
Haji

Answer (score 2):

Without more details it's quite hard to know what the issue might be.

A neat trick to use for these kind of issues, is that you can actually attach to the Blend process from the Visual Studio debugger. Go to Debug -> Attach to Process, find the Blend.exe process and attach to that, then try opening the view in Blend, this should allow you to debug what's going on.

For step by step instructions on this, have a look at: [Debugging Design-Time Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2008/06/19/debugging-design-time-exceptions.aspx)

Good luck!